# "smaller" footline in scrreprt

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, typearea, scrlayer-scrpage

I want to use a smaller (as in height). I read in the KOMA-Script documentation that increasing the DIV value will reduce the size of headers and footers and enlarge the typearea (where the main part is) of the document. As you can see below i already increased the value to 18, but the footer is still huge and so much space on the page is wasted. The problem is that the institute i write this for has wants the paper to be maximum 12 pages long.

This is my first LaTeX/KOMA-Script work and it is also my final paper.

Below is a MWE, but it feels like it is better in this example than in my original document.

```
\documentclass[headings=small,a4paper,fontsize=10pt,
               twoside=false,DIV=18,BCOR=5mm,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,ilines]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document} 
   \chapter{dummy}
   dummy-text\footnote{dummynote}
   \pagebreak
   dummy-text\footnote{dummynote}
   \chapter{dummy2}
   \section{dummy}
   dummy-text\footnote{dummynote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` so that other users can reproduce your problem and have something to build their answer on.

Comment: You can also use package `geometry` to make an ugly document. A DIV of 18 will make the text unreadable. You could resolve some of the issues by setting it in two columns.

Comment: @Pier Paolo Hello, thank you for welcoming me! I edited the post to add a MWE.

Comment: @Johannes_B
I already tried it with geometry and you are right it was very ugly and not the way i wanted it to look like. Is changing the DIV=Value best practice or can you recommend some other way to change the height of the footer?

Comment: KOMA (typearea) provides with DIV a mechanism that provides some reasonable type areas. There is a calculation going on in the background that ensures, that the proportion of height to width is in some limited values. You now are trying to override thos calculations. There is no point in using DIV to break it later. Use the proper tool, `geometry` to make the document ugly.

Comment: You can add the pagemark to the header and have an empty footer. Now being able to drop it completely.

Comment: Having page limits may be stupid, but cheating isn't the way to get there. Make the text shorter.

Comment: Usually, the option `headsepline` is given globally. It will toggle `headinclude` as well, as is introduced and reasoned in the documentation. Once this is done, the header will fit proper on the page.

Comment: The problem actually is that there is not so much text to shorten, there is plenty of figures which are causing a lot of whitespace. A smaller footer would provide more opportunities to fit another figure or table in this space.

Comment: @hexxolord If you are free to chose the layout of your document, you could have a look at the [`tufte` classes](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex), which do look good, and are very compact.

Comment: If the figures are "causing a lot of whitespace": Why do they cause a lot of whitespace? Do you allow them to float? If not, try to do so. Are they small and have a lot of whitespace at the left and right side? Maybe you could put two or more figures side by side or put the caption beside the figure (see `captionbeside` in the KOMA-Script manual).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used `\setlength{\footheight}{0mm}` to semi-achieve my goal. Thanks for your advice anyways. Especially @Johannes_B who clarified a lot of the mechanics.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Though this seems to be a comment, apparently it solved (maybe partly) the OPs problem. So it is an answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I might be new to tex.stackexchange.com, but as Johannes_B stated, for me this is a legitimate answer thats why i put it at as one and marked the question as solved.

Comment: @hexxorlord: If it's sufficient for you...

Comment: Setting `\footheight` to 0mm results in a warning message and auto-enlarging of `\footheight`. Better use option `footlines=1`. However, both does not reduce the size of the foot margin but only the position of the page footer.

Answer (score 4):

Use option `usegeometry` for the KOMA-Script class `scrreprt`. Then you can load package `geometry` and set only the bottom margin to your needs.

```
\documentclass[headings=small,a4paper,fontsize=10pt,
               twoside=false,BCOR=5mm,DIV=18,
              usegeometry% <- added
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,ilines]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}% <- added

\begin{document} 
   \chapter{dummy}
   dummy-text\footnote{dummynote}
   \pagebreak
   dummy-text\footnote{dummynote}
   \chapter{dummy2}
   \section{dummy}
   dummy-text\footnote{dummynote}
\end{document
```

Comment: You (*i.e.*, me) learn something new every day :)